# Rocket chat iframe integration. Browser's navigation issue

Tags: javascript, rocket.chat

I have integrated Rocket Chat in my app. I am having an issue, when I am trying to use browser's navigation (go back button, go forward button), instead of navigating the app screen, it navigates the rocket chat iframe.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue while integrating the rocketchat and following solution worked for me:

**The Issue**

1) when initiating the iframe either by writing explicitly in the html or appending it to the DOM through javascript , an new entry of rocketchat's url is pushed in the browser's history stack

2)If you are sending token from your parent application to the rocket chat in the iframe to login, Rocket chat will redirect if login is successful from the root_url to root_url/home creating a new entry in the browser history stack

3)Every time you click a anchor tag (enter a room etc) in the rocket chat (inside iframe) another entry is created and pushed in the browser history stack

Now when the app gets loaded the stack looks like this even if the iframe is hidden by default in the beginning

- rocketchat_url/home
- rocketchat_url
- app_url

now if you press the back button  the browser will go to rocketchat_url , the route will find out that a token is already present in the localstorage so it will redirect again to /home, therefore we will keep pressing the back button and it wont work

**Solution**

We need to avoid creating a new entry in the browser's stack for all the three points I mention above

1 & 2) Instead of giving url to the iframe in the html directly, we can add an empty iframe first, that will create a window object for that iframe , now we can access that window and use location.replace to set the url, this will replace the current entry in the browser history instead of creating a new one , this will work for the first point, for the second point we can directly give the '/home' url so that rocket chat doesnt have to redirect after login, if you are not login /home page will automatically fetch the token from your app if youre using postMessage to send the token.

```
$('body').append(`<iframe id="chat"></iframe>`);
$('iframe#chat')[0].contentWindow.location.replace(chat._baseUrl+'/home');
```

3)Adding an event listener on all the anchor tags in rocket chat that will replace the current entry in the history stack with the anchor tag's url so that when click is performed and browser tries to create new entry it finds the same entry already present on top of the stack and does not create a new entry

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            anchor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                history.replaceState(null, null, anchor.href);
            }, false);
        }
```

^above code needs to be run inside the iframe window

Hope this will give you enough insight to solve the issue